# Как сделать проверку введенного текста в C#?

Tags: c#

Например если пользователь введет значения не совпадающие с условием, программа будет просить конкретное значение

Comment: Текст вводят куда? В консоль, в textBox? какой тип проекта WPF WinForm ConsoleApp?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Answer (score 2):

Проверку или валидацию вводимых пользователем данных обычно организуют в классах модели вашего приложения. Для этого есть 3 способа:

1) [DataAnnotations](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations?view=netframework-4.7.2) хороший пример [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/22.1.php)

2) реализация в классе модели интерфейса [IDataErrorInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.idataerrorinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)

3) реализация в классе модели интерфейса [INotifyDataErrorInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifydataerrorinfo?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Вот пример реализации `IDataErrorInfo` для простейшего класса `Person`

```
public class Person : IDataErrorInfo
{

    public static readonly string Dummy = "<?>";
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }


    #region Реализация IDataErrorInfo
    public string _Error;
    public string Error => _Error;
    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            if (columnName.Equals(nameof(FirstName)) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName))
            {
                _Error = "FirstName";
                return "Имя не может быть пустым";
            }

            if (columnName.Equals(nameof(FirstName)) && FirstName.Contains(Dummy))
            {
                _Error = "FirstName";
                return "Укажите имя";
            }

            if (columnName.Equals(nameof(LastName)) && String.IsNullOrEmpty(LastName))
            {
                _Error = "LastName";
                return "Фамилия не может быть пустой";
            }

            if (columnName.Equals(nameof(LastName)) && LastName.Contains(Dummy))
            {
                _Error = "LastName";
                return "Укажите фамилию";
            }

            _Error = String.Empty;
            return _Error;
        }
    } 
    #endregion
}
```

И так это работает в WinForm приложении
[image: пример работы]

Отображение сообщений об ошибках реализуется с помощью [ErrorProvider](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider?view=netframework-4.7.2)
Пример можно скачать [здесь](https://yadi.sk/d/5Vi4O5Cu8aUInQ)

Answer (score 0):

Проверка может осуществляться различными способами.
Например, проверка на пустую или null строку метод string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(string value)

В общем случае, все можно провалидировать регулярными выражениями.
Например номера телефонов, даты и многое другое.

Большой плюс в том, что регулярные выражения можно использовать везде(в разных ЯП), поэтому это действительно полезные знания.

Почитать можно тут:
https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expressions

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
string s;

while ((s = Console.ReadLine()) != "Енот")
  Console.WriteLine(@"Вместо слова ""Енот"" вы написали ""{0}""", s);

Console.WriteLine("Ура, {0}!", s);
```